# netsh dhcp isn't working on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, dhcp, netsh

Gents,

I am trying to run the following command on a fresh Windows Server 2008 box.

netsh dhcp server 10.2.x.x scope 10.2.x.x show client

and I am given the following error

the following command could not be found:

If I run this on my local windows 7 machien it's fine.

Perhaps I am missing some libraries or options? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could be wrong, but do you need the DHCP Server role installed on the box before it will let you use the command line tools?

Comment: @SmallClanger:  Add your comment as an answer and @Daniel can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You need the DHCP Server role installed on the box before it will let you use the command line tools.

(+Credit to SmallClanger who provided this answer in a comment. -Credit for not posting it as an answer that could be accepted, or voted up/down)

Answer (score 0):

"show client" doesn't exist on my Windows 7 machine or a fresh install of Windows Server 2008 R2.

What does exist is "show alias" and "show helper".